# Abstract Generic ODataController Leads To 'No HTTP resource was found'

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-web-api-odata

I have this base ODataController

```
public abstract class BaseController<T> : ODataController where T : class
{
    [EnableQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(Repository.AsQueryable());
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int key)
    {
        var entity = Repository.GetByKey(key);
        return Ok(entity);
    }
}
```

And this derived controller

```
public class FoosController : BaseController<Foo>
{

}
```

I can hit `.../odata/foos(1)` just fine. But `.../odata/foos` give this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:44300/odata/Foos'.",
        "innererror": {
            "message": "No action was found on the controller 'Foos' that matches the request.",
            "type": "",
            "stacktrace": ""
        }
    }
}
```

I have to make `Get()` virtual and then override it in the derived controller. Like this:

```
public class FoosController : BaseController<Foo>
{
    [EnableQuery]
    [ODataRoute("Foos")]
    public override IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return base.Get();
    }
}
```

Why doesn't `Get()` in the base controller work, when `Get(1)` does?

Comment: What does `Repository.AsQueryable()` do? `Repository.GetByKey(key)` calls a method of your repository, but the first one looks odd to me. Shouldn't it be something like `Repository.GetEverythingMEthod().AsQueryable()`?

Comment: `Repository.AsQueryable()` is just `DbSet<T>.AsQueryable()`. I stripped out the injection of `Repository` because that shouldn't have anything to do with the routing :)